# Java annotation for Null but neither Empty nor Blank

Tags: java, validation

Is there are any java annotation(s) that can validate like the example below?

```
String test;
test = null; //valid
test = ""; //invalid
test = " "; //invalid
test = "Some values"; //valid
```

Comment: No, but you can write one of your own. :)

Comment: This would be some kind of assurance. This is, what [mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) are for. I do not think that there is an annotation for this (at least not in plain Java).

Comment: any @Pattern(regexp = xxx)  ???

Answer (score 55):

You need to create a custom annotation: `@NullOrNotBlank`

First create the custom annotation: `NullOrNotBlank.java`

```java
@Target( {ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NullOrNotBlankValidator.class)
public @interface NullOrNotBlank {
    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.NullOrNotBlank.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then the actual validator: `NullOrNotBlankValidator.java`

```java
public class NullOrNotBlankValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NullOrNotBlank, String> {

    public void initialize(NullOrNotBlank parameters) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return value == null || value.trim().length() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick one-liner for the validation: `return str == null || str.trim().length() > 0;`

Comment: @JeffersonLima I am not sure why my code is so verbose (I don't even like regex). Your one liner is spot on.

Comment: Great solution, I replaced the isValid check with: `return value == null || !value.isBlank();` since I am using Java 11.

Comment: FYI, this is possible to do without a custom annotation using [javax.validation.constraints.Size](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html). I've added an answer for this.

Comment: @Phil unfortunately the Size annotation will count blank spaces, so cannot be used in this instance.

Answer (score 35):

There isn't such an annotation in either javax.validation or Hibernate Validator.  There was a [request to add one to Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-811) but it was closed as "won't fix" due to the possibility of writing your own relatively easily.  The suggest solution was to either use your own annotation type defined like this:

```
@ConstraintComposition(OR)
@Null
@NotBlank
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface NullOrNotBlank {
    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NullOrNotBlank.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

or to use the `@Pattern` annotation with a regular expression that requires a non-whitespace character to be present (as the Pattern annotation [accepts nulls and does not match them against the pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)).

Comment: +1 for the `@Pattern` idea. This is great because many of the built-in annotations pass for null so that they don't conflict with `@NotNull`

Answer (score 9):

This is possible without creating a custom annotation, by using [javax.validation.constraints.Size](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html)

```java
// Null values are considered valid
@Size(min=1) String test;
```

However as [theprogrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6059506/theprogrammer) points out, blank strings such as `" "` are considered valid, which is not the case for `@NotBlank`.

Comment: such underrated solution +1

Comment: But it will break blank strings of length 1 like "_"(where _ means space)

Comment: This annotation is not applied for empty string, which is a string without any character `""` . It works if you have a string with few characters, `"abc"` , but it doesn't work if you have an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 7):

Where is a nice `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` annotation.

You can annotate the field with:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?!\\s*$).+", message = "must not be blank")
```

This checks if field matches regex. The regex itself is **something but not blank** ([see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085539/regular-expression-for-anything-but-an-empty-string/3085553#3085553)). It uses negative lookahead.

Comment: This regex is valid but I tried using it and SonarQube flagged it as a security hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create your own constraint validator,

```
//custom annotation
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomCheck.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomConstarint {
    String message() default "Invalid data";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
} 

//validation logic goes here
public class CustomCheck implements 
  ConstraintValidator<CustomConstarint, String> {
 
    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomConstarint customConstarint) {
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String field,
      ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        //write your logic to validate the field
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Answer (score -7):

Did you try [Hibernate-Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/)? I think that's what you are looking for.

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class MyModel  {

    @NotNull
    private String  str1;

    @NotEmpty
    private String  str2;

    @NotBlank
    private String  str3;

}
```

Comment: No, I don't think so, I want all those validation over my single variable

Comment: `@NotBlank` validates for all of your requirements on a single variable. I just added the others if you want less validation. E.g. if your variable may contain blank char then use `@NotEmpty` or if it may contain empty string then use `@NotNull`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137307/in-hibernate-validator-4-1-what-is-the-difference-between-notnull-notempty

Comment: I just try to explain the details of related to your questions. Not all. What's wrong?

Comment: None of these matches the requirements in the question, which are that the value should not be empty but may still be null.  All of these validation constraints fail on null.