# Javax.Validation - allow null but validate if the value is not

Tags: java, validation

I am using javax `Validation.constraints` and I want to validate input but allow it to be null, my POJO:

```
public class somePOJO{
    @NotNull
    @Size(min =2, max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z \\s\\-]*$")
    private String country;

    @Size(min =2,max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z \\s\\-]*$")
    private String state;
    //gettes, setters.....

}
```

I want to validate `state` for example with  `@Pattern` and `@size` only if it not `null`.

Is there a way to do it with using [custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132477/java-annotation-for-null-but-neither-empty-nor-blank)?

Comment: are you sure that you had import this one? 
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

Comment: all imports from - `import javax.validation.constraints.*;`

Comment: How are you create this pojo object? is it some REST service?

Comment: Yes Spring-boot controller.

Comment: Please, show your controller code

Comment: Why? I want to do the validation using Validation.constraints.

Comment: You can use Alternation Constructs in regular expressions to separate multiple patterns. Just separate patterns using pipe '|' i.e. append regex for null/empty string based on your requirement to your existing regex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works out of the box as you would expect e.g. in Spring Boot, 2.1.0 (and also with Quarkus FWIW).

Here is the full version of the POJO (please notice, that I promote an immutable class):

```
package sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53207105;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class SomePOJO {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min =2, max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z \\s\\-]*$")
    private final String country;

    @Size(min =2,max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z \\s\\-]*$")
    private final String state;

    public SomePOJO(String country, String state) {
        this.country = country;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

}
```

If you are concerned with empty strings you can accept them by adding a trailing pipe to the regular expression (which will mean "this expression OR empty string"), although this will break the `Size()` requirement:

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z \\s\\-]*$|")
```

Full version of the controller:

```
package sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53207105;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/q53207105", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test(@Valid @RequestBody SomePOJO somePOJO) {
        System.out.println("somePOJO.getCountry() = " + somePOJO.getCountry());
        System.out.println("somePOJO.getState() = " + somePOJO.getState());
    }

}
```

Calling http://localhost:8080/q53207105 with:

```
{
    "country": "USA",
    "state": "California" 
}
```

Prints:

```
somePOJO.getCountry() = USA
somePOJO.getState() = California
```

Calling http://localhost:8080/q53207105 with:

```
{
    "country": "USA",
}
```

Prints:

```
somePOJO.getCountry() = USA
somePOJO.getState() = null
```

If you tell me your Spring boot version, I might help more.

Comment: You can find the code here: https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q53207105-nullable-validation

Comment: This is not going to work when an empty string is passed. You have to set an **InitBinder** of  **StringTrimmerEditor** in your controller to work in both cases when an empty string or null is passed from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alternation Constructs in regular expressions to separate multiple patterns. Just separate patterns using pipe '|' i.e. append regex for null/empty string based on your requirement to your existing regex. Sample below:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z \\s\\-]*|)$
```

May not be exact, but hope you got the idea.

Comment: It is possible but then I will need to remove the @Size validation.

Comment: You can put in {2,50} for size validation also, in the regular expression itself.

Comment: I wonder the same. Please try out and accept as answer if it works for you.

Comment: It is a workaround if there aren't butter answers I will.

Answer (score 1):

Your POJP will work as expected when there is a **StringTrimmerEditor** is set in an **InitBinder**.

You can have an application wide InitBinder, having a class like below in your project.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomControllerAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }
}
```