# How to exclude validation on specific fields in Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator

I've to ignore the validation if value is not set on specific fields. For instance, I've `name`, `productId`, `productSerial`, `productDesc` and `productPrice`

In this, `name` is mandatory field so always validation happens, rest of the fields are **`optional`** but if value is set in these fields I've to validate. So I wrote custom validator for these optional fields and for `name` I'm using `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` like this `@NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")`

I get all these value in `Map` from upstream app and set these value in my `Java bean` and perform the `validation`.

If all the fields are available in `Map`, validation is working without any issue but if user set only `name` which is mandatory and leave the optional field - my custom validator trying to validate and throwing `NullPointerException` which I don't want.

I want my custom validator to validate if values are set on these optional fields else ignore the validation - I don't know how to achieve this :( It would be really appreciated if someone can help me with this and provide some sample example.

**Working scenario:**

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", "Apple"); // Always user will set this value - Mandatory

map.put("productId", "2342342"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
map.put("productSerial", "4334DDF43"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
map.put("productDesc", "iPhone"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
map.put("productPrice", "1303"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set

// Once I get the map from upstream, I've to set the map value in my bean and validate 
Product product = new Product();
product.setName(map.get("name"));
product.setProductId(map.get("productId"));
product.setProductSerial(map.get("productSerial"));
product.setProductDesc(map.get("productDesc"));
product.setProductPrice(map.get("productPrice"));
```

**Getting NullPointerException when below scenario occurs**

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", "Apple"); 

Product product = new Product();
product.setName(map.get("name"));
product.setProductId(map.get("productId"));
product.setProductSerial(map.get("productSerial"));
product.setProductDesc(map.get("productDesc"));
product.setProductPrice(map.get("productPrice"));
```

**Please find my code below:**

**Product.java**

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@ValidParam
public class Product {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    private String productId;
    private String productSerial;
    private String productDesc;
    private String productPrice;
}
```

**ValidParam.java**

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProductValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidParam {
    String message() default "Invalid product data.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**ProductValidator.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;



public class ProductValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidParam, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        String productId = (String) new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue("productId");
        String productSerial = (String) new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue("productSerial");


        String productDesc = (String) new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue("productDesc");
        String productPrice = (String) new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue("productPrice");



        if ((productId != null || productSerial != null) || (productDesc != null && productPrice != null)) {
            System.out.println("validation success");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("validation failed");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I get this Map from the upstream app
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("name", "Apple"); // Always user will set this value - Mandatory
        map.put("productId", "2342342"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
        map.put("productSerial", "4334DDF43"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
        map.put("productDesc", "iPhone"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
        map.put("productPrice", "1303"); // Optional but need to validate if this value is set
       
 // Once I get the map from upstream, I've to set the map value in my bean and validate 
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setName(map.get("name"));
            product.setProductId(map.get("productId"));
            product.setProductSerial(map.get("productSerial"));
            product.setProductDesc(map.get("productDesc"));
            product.setProductPrice(map.get("productPrice"));
            ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
            Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Product>> violations = validator.validate(product);
            for (ConstraintViolation<Product> violation : violations) {
                System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
                throw new NullPointerException(violation.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208700/2599899) to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ArthurKlezovich I tried specifying @Size(min =2,max=50) still 'CustomValidator' class try to validate the productId. Apologize if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Are you using Spring ? Can you post this code to Github ?

Comment: Yes I'm using Spring, I have all my code in the original post. If you want I can put in the Github