# Bean Validation API, possible to dynamically indicate to validator to ignore a specific constraint annotation on a specific field of POJO

Tags: java, validation, constraints, bean-validation

I have a POJO with some fields annotated with `@NotEmpty`:

```java
public class SampleFormInputDTO {

  @NotEmpty
  private String textarea;

  private int myInt = 0;

  @NotEmpty
  private String myText = "somevalue";

  public String getTextarea() {
    return textarea;
  }

  public void setTextarea(String textarea) {
    this.textarea = textarea;
  }
}
```

The intention is that the fields will be checked to ensure they contain a value i.e not null and not empty.

If I create an instance of `SampleFormInputDTO` using no-args constructor, the field `textarea` will be null initially so should and does fail validation as expected.

```java
SampleFormInputDTO sampleFormInputDTO = new SampleFormInputDTO();

ValidatorFactory validatorFactory =
    Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
        .buildValidatorFactory();

Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator(sampleFormInputDTO);

Set<ConstraintViolation<SampleFormInputDTO>> violationSet = validator.validate();
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to dynamically / programmatically indicate to the validator instance to not validate a specific constraint annotation for a specific field?

Suppose I've determined, as part of handling a REST API invocation that I want the field `textarea` of type `SampleFormInputDTO` to allow empty strings dynamically, but only for that specific field. Not affecting any constraint annotations that may be present on other fields in the same POJO.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at the [validation groups](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0.html#validationapi-validatorapi-groups).

```java
public class SampleFormInputDTO {

  @NotEmpty(groups = Group1.class)
  private String textarea;

  private int myInt = 0;

  @NotEmpty
  private String myText = "somevalue";

  public String getTextarea() {
    return textarea;
  }

  public void setTextarea(String textarea) {
    this.textarea = textarea;
  }
}
```

Then you can control which constraints are included in validation and which are not, for example:

```
validator.validate(sampleFormInputDTO);
```

will only check `myText` property, but then something like:

```
validator.validate(sampleFormInputDTO, Group1.class, Default.class);
```

will validate both.

Comment: This approach involves modifying the source, I'm looking to instruct the validator to ignore `@NotEmpty` constraint annotation for a particular field at runtime/dynamically .. without modifying the source code

Comment: @bobbyrne01 This allows you to determine the behavior dynamically, by specifying the group(s) based on some condition at run-time. Of course, it still involves modifying the annotations in the POJO.

Comment: I dont want consumers of my framework to have to be concerned with specifying groups inside the annotations, and as I mentioned already, have to modify the source code

Comment: @bobbyrne01, you might want to describe your constraints (like not modifying the pojo) in the question then and be more specific about what you mean by "dynamic".  For example, one could do something similar to what you are asking by defining the constraints programmatically. But then again it may not fit your solution constraints.

Answer (score -1):

So if I understood correctly, your problem is that you want to validate the fields but in case an empty object has been submitted you do not want to through an exception,
you can try two scenarios, first one is to put the validation inside the args constructor, therefor when using the no args constructore no validation well happen, check this ex:

```
public class Employee {
...
  public Employee (@NotNull String name) { ... }

  public void setSalary(
      @NotNull
      @Digits(integer=6, fraction=2) BigDecimal salary,
      @NotNull
      @ValidCurrency
      String currencyType) {
    ...
  }
...
}
```

link is [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-custom-validation/)

or you can build your own custom validation:
check [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-custom-validation/)

also I believe you can use the regex and provide a pattern that suits your case
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207105/javax-validation-allow-null-but-validate-if-the-value-is-not/53208700#53208700)

Comment: Both of the approaches you mentioned involve modifying the source, I'm looking to instruct the validator to ignore `@NotEmpty` constraint annotation for a particular field at runtime/dynamically .. without modifying the source code

Comment: ok got you , give this [paper](https://www.ijcttjournal.org/2019/Volume-67%20Issue-3/IJCTT-V67I3P121.pdf) a look , it uses buddy byte lib to generate run-time validation class, this will make u control over the validation at runtime, through API call for example, Note I have not tried this but you can give  it a look