how to check multiple variables for 1 condition in java
There are multilpe variables inside ValidateBankAccountRequest Object where I have to validate few objects that it should not be null.
If one of them is null, throw an error.
i tried with the below one. Is there a better way to optimize the same?
  if (v.getEmail().isEmpty() || v.getPrinFirstName().isEmpty() || v.getPrinLastName().isEmpty() || v.getPrinAddrStreet().isEmpty() || v.getPrinAddrCity().isEmpty() || v.getPrinAddrPostalCode().isEmpty()
        ||v.getPrinAddrState().isEmpty()|| v.getPrinAddrCountry().isEmpty() || v.getPrinPhone().isEmpty() || v.getSsn().isEmpty() || v.getDbaName().isEmpty()|| v.getDbaAddrStreet().isEmpty() || v.getDbaAddrCity().isEmpty()
        || v.getDbaAddrPostalCode().isEmpty() || v.getDbaAddrState().isEmpty() || v.getDbaAddrCountry().isEmpty() || v.getDbaPhone().isEmpty() || v.getLglName().isEmpty() || v.getLglAddrStreet().isEmpty() || v.getLglAddrCity().isEmpty() || v.getLglAddrPostalCode().isEmpty()
                || v.getLglAddrState().isEmpty() || v.getLglAddrCountry().isEmpty() || v.getLglPhone().isEmpty() || v.getTaxId().isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("BAD_REQUEST");
        }


You can create custom annotations , refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132477/java-annotation-for-null-but-neither-empty-nor-blank

Which framework are you using, certainly there are annotations to use, depending on that.

You say that you want to check for nulls, but the code in your question is not. Method isEmpty() does not check for null. If, for example, v.getEmail() returns null, your code will throw NullPointerException.

BTW check the Objects.requireNonNull methods (also nonNull, isNull)

Please edit the question to include what you think needs to be optimized and by what metric, as well as the current performance based on that metric and what an acceptable improved performance by that same metric would be. Otherwise this question is not within scope here on Stack Overflow.

Using this example (Java version 8 or higher):
String a = "a";
String b = null;
String c = "";

if (Stream.of(a, b, c).anyMatch(x -> x == null || x.isEmpty()))
    throw new RuntimeException("Null or empty value found...");

The above code will throw the exception when there is a null or an empty value for any of the three string variables. Since, you are looking for null values and also empty strings, you need to check for both in the predicate.
If you don't check for a null in the predicate, there can be a NullPointerException.
Now, your code:
if (v.getEmail().isEmpty() || v.getPrinFirstName().isEmpty() || ... ) {
    throw new BadRequestException("BAD_REQUEST");
}

can be written as:
if (Stream.of(v.getEmail(), v.getPrinFirstName(), ...).anyMatch(x -> x == null || x.isEmpty())) {
    throw new BadRequestException("BAD_REQUEST"); 
}


Speaking of computational optimization, there isn't a lot to do. Optimizing for readability, I would suggest extracting the condition to a method operating on v. Otherwise, to reduce the number of times you write.isEmpty you could do something like:
Stream.of(
    v.getEmail(), 
    v.getPrinFirstName(), 
    v.getPrinLastName() 
    ... 
    ).anyMatch(String::isEmpty);

Now, this would throw a NullPointerException at String::isEmpty. If you want to extend functionality to check for null-values as well, you could replace the final step with .anyMatch(str -> str == null || str.isEmpty()) or use some built in method if you already use a framework which contains this. (I.e. with spring you could use StringUtils::isEmpty)

Keep in mind that this have slightly different semantic. It will invoke all method even if first one return empty value.

It does not invoke all methods. Similar to chaining ||, the method .anyMatch will short circuit once it finds something which meets the condition.

No, getEmail, getPrinFirstName etc called before first isEmpty is called.

Right, all getters will be invoked. I stand corrected.

You may avoid it by creating stream of functions, then invoke them in map. Like Stream.of(SomeType::getEmail).map(f -> f.apply(v)).anyMatch(String::isEmpty)

Also, we must assume that none of those getters returns null

Correct. If spring is used, it's straightforward to switch to .anyMatch(StringUtils::isEmpty). Otherwise it can be implemented with .anyMatch(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty())

Jakarta Validation
This looks like a job for Jakarta Validation, formerly known as Bean Validation. See tutorial.
With this framework, you can annotate each field of your class with one or more validation constraints. Some constraints are predefined, such as @NotEmpty, @NotBlank, and @Email. And you can write code to define your own constraints.
At runtime, you can invoke the framework to ask if an object is valid, meaning all constraints have been met. You can ask which fields are violating their constraints.
Usage is easy.
public class Customer {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=1, max=24)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=1, max=24)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    private String email;

    …
}

The Jakarta EE project, including Jakarta Validation, defines only the API (interfaces), not the implementation.
You have two routes to using this framework.

The simple direct route is to include the only implementation available currently, Hibernate Validator.
Or, you may choose to make only calls against the API, which would allow you to switch to another implementation in the future without changing your code base.

If writing a web app to be deployed to an app server that complies with Jakarta EE, go the second route. The app server provides a copy of both the API and the implementation, so do not bundle either in your final app artifact.
If writing a console app or a desktop (GUI such as Swing, JavaFX, SWT) app, choose either route. If you choose the second route, bundle both the API and the implementation within your final app artifact.

Excellent recommendation! One should avoid reinventing the wheel and should use these well-tested and widely used libraries. It also makes the code clean.

You're going to have to check them all somewhere. What I'd personally prefer is adding a method to whatever "v" is and have that do the checks, then return true or false depending on whether the checks passed or failed (with maybe a String or enum being set when the checks fail indicating the first failure if you want to be fancy).
so you'd get something akin to if (!v.isValid()) { throw new BadRequestException(BAD_REQUEST); }
This also future proofs "v" in that if it ever adds fields to be checked the only place the checks need to be changed is in the class itself, not anywhere that uses it.
