# No @NotBlank validator for type String

Tags: spring-boot, javax.validation

I keep getting validator error for quite simple configuration class

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Component
@Data
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class TestProperties {
    @NotBlank
    String uri;
}
```

Error is self explaining:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'uri'
```

But according to spring boot documentation this should work.

Comment: It turns out Spring Boot uses Hibernate validator to make things work. I tries to use Bean Validation 2 annotations with Hibernate 5. Which obviously didn't work.

Comment: you're a life saver! spring-boot-starter-web 1.5.8 was using hibernate-validator 5.x.x. So I just added an exclusion to that dependency and fixed my issue. You should make an answer and mark it!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and solved it.

As Yogi stated in his answer, there are two implementations:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
```

and

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
```

Switching from the `javax` implementation to the `hibernate` one solved the issue.

Since I didn't use Spring boot, I had to add to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;` is depricated

Answer (score 5):

According to Spring-Boot documentation and maven central repo the:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

has the validator included. If you have not spring-boot-starter-web included to your dependencies you can just add the validator:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I saw a [similar question](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/unexpectedtypeexception-error/) outside this forum and discovered that the error comes up whenever you try to put `@NotBlank` annotation on any non-string type field. In my case, the `javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException` came up when I annotated a field of type Byte with `@NotBlank`. So I imported `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`, changed the annotation on the Byte field to `@NotNull` and the error disappeared.

I previously tried replacing `import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;` with `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;` to kill the error, but I got a deprecation warning. Programmers are discouraged from using deprecated program elements, so I advise that you use `@NotNull` annotation instead.

To understand the differences between `@NotBlank` and `@NotNull`, see this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137307/in-hibernate-validator-4-1-what-is-the-difference-between-notnull-notempty). That way, you get to decide if `@NotNull` fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked okay when running as a standalone application, but gave this same error when running as a WAR; in order to make it work, it was necessary to explicitly import the hibernate-validator as a dependency in order to make it work when running as a WAR:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below options,which works with Spring JPA:

1. org.hibernate.validator.constraints.**NotBlank**
2. javax.validation.constraints.**NotNull**

Answer (score -3):

I have always used @NotNull.

I think the corresponding POM code is

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: That's not what he was asking about. `@NotNull` and `@NotBlank` have different semantics for `String`s